# When to avoid Async Await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, stack, overflow

Async/Await is nice way to code responsive GUI but as I suppose cheese here isn't free. I think only the way to realize Await statement is a memory stack. Each time you call Await, there is a new pointer put in memory stack. Therefore if you call to frequently Await and result delays, you get stack overflow (that is the keyword you can't search here :))

Let's suppose we check some connection status asynchronously periodically.
Create a simple windows forms project with Form1 and form code is here.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testasync
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int CallCount = 0;
        int CalBackCount = 0;
        Random r = new Random();

        private Button butStart = new Button();
        private Button butStop = new Button();
        private Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        private Label labCalls =new Label();
        private Label labReturns = new Label();

        public Form1()
        {
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(450, 200);

            butStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(51, 38);
            butStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(139, 47);
            butStart.Text = "Start";
            butStart.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.butStart_Click);

            butStop.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(237, 38);
            butStop.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(139, 47);
            butStop.Text = "Stop";
            butStop.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.butStop_Click);

            labCalls.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(48, 149);
            labCalls.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23);

            labReturns.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(237, 149);
            labReturns.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23);

            Controls.Add(this.labCalls);
            Controls.Add(this.labReturns);
            Controls.Add(this.butStart);
            Controls.Add(this.butStop);


            timer1.Interval = 5;
            timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        }

        private void butStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void butStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }


        private async Task myWork()
        {
            CallCount++;
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            if (r.Next(100)>10) //Check Connection
                await Task.Delay(100000000);
            CalBackCount++;
        }

        private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labCalls.Text = CallCount.ToString();
            await myWork();
            labReturns.Text = CalBackCount.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

instead of checking connection I use random check to wait long time for connection response.

If we run the project and hit start button, we'll see that memory consumption by the application rises by time. Therefore I suppose this is not the right way to use `Await` statement, I think better way is use threading with delegates or nice component BackgroundWorker with progress events. Or maybe there are better solutions?

Comment: You are overthinking this, the async and await pattern will not cause a stack overflow by itself, recursion will though. Secondly, .net will not aggressively give memory back to the operating system (that has a true cost and overhead), it will when it thinks it needs to.. however if you think you have a memory leak you will need to use the right tool, like a memory profiler

Comment: @TheGeneral , how do you think, which is better way for this task - something like infinitive asynchronous ping? Is Sync/Await ok with infinitive calls with delayed responses?

Comment: You are creating a new task every 5 milliseconds! So yes, you have a memory leak but it is not because of the await. You need some mechanism to limit the amount of tasks running in parallel.

Comment: @KlausGütter , thanks for the comment, so I suppose, in this case, I should check tasks states before run a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions on how `async-await` works aren't correct.

Each asynchronous method will be converted in a state machine that splits the method into several methods (the parts between the start, awaits and end) and orchestrates its execution.

A rogue asynchronous method will more likely exhaust the heap than the stack.